# Firebase recycleradapter with filter using searchview

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a project list in firebase database and it is listed in Recyclerview using firebaserecycleradapter. It works fine. I also have a searchview to filter the list based on search query. But the adapter doesn't show the filtered list. The recyclerview goes blank when I type the query in searchview. Could anyone highlight the mistake in my coding and correct me to get the desired result. I have given below the coding.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private RecyclerView PList;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder> FBRA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        PList = findViewById(R.id.ProjList);
        PList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        PList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Projects");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<project> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<project>()
                .setQuery(mDatabase, project.class).build();
        FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull project model) {
                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String proj_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                holder.prname.setText(model.getPname());
                holder.prlocation.setText(model.getPlocation());
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent detactivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                        detactivity.putExtra("ProjID", proj_key);
                        startActivity(detactivity);
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ProjViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.proj_row, parent, false);
                ProjViewHolder vh = new ProjViewHolder(view);
                return vh;
            }
        };
        PList.setAdapter(FBRA);
        FBRA.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        final MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Project");
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    fbsearch(query);
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    fbsearch(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void fbsearch (String searchText){
        String pquery = searchText.toLowerCase();
        Query sQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("pname").equalTo(pquery);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<project> soptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<project>()
                .setQuery(sQuery, project.class).build();
        FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder>(soptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull project model) {
                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String proj_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                holder.prname.setText(model.getPname());
                holder.prlocation.setText(model.getPlocation());
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent detactivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                        detactivity.putExtra("ProjID", proj_key);
                        startActivity(detactivity);
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ProjViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.proj_row, parent, false);
                ProjViewHolder vh = new ProjViewHolder(view);
                return vh;
            }
        };

        PList.setAdapter(FBRA);
        FBRA.startListening();
    }

    public class ProjViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView prname, prlocation, prservice, prvalue, practual;
        public ProjViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            prname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FPName);
            prlocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FPLocation);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FBRA.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was able to identify the problem in the code. As the query is case sensitive, the search list was not shown. I created a new field to store the project name in lower case. Then I made the query to the new field. The corrected code is given below.

```
  private void fbsearch (String searchText){
    String pquery = searchText.toLowerCase();
    Query sQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("pnamelowcase").startAt(pquery).endAt(pquery + "\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<project> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<project>()
            .setQuery(sQuery, project.class).setLifecycleOwner(this).build();
    FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull project model) {
            String proj_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            holder.prname.setText(model.getPname());
            holder.prlocation.setText(model.getPlocation());
            holder.prservice.setText(model.getPservice());
            holder.prvalue.setText(model.getPvalue());
            holder.practual.setText(model.getPactual());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent detactivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                    detactivity.putExtra("ProjID", proj_key);
                    startActivity(detactivity);
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ProjViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.proj_row, parent, false);
   //         ProjViewHolder vh = new ProjViewHolder(view);
            return new ProjViewHolder(view);

        }
    };
    PList.setAdapter(FBRA);
}
```

What I noticed that **Query** only works with *startAt* and *endAt* If I change to any other queries such as *equalTo*, It doesn't work.

I have also noticed one more issue that normal list is not shown once the searchview is closed. If anyone find the issue in my code, please highlight it and tell me why other queries don't work and how to get back the original list once the searchview is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try researching through debug, console print or log, or even toasts in-app about the *reference* queries inside your FirebaseRecyclerOptions<> declaration. There are also many other parameters in FirebaseDatabase queries, such as orderByKey(), orderByChild(), etc... Also I recommend putting *.setLifecycleOwner(this)* to your FirebaseRecycleOptions inside your search function.